# MARS MIPS Simulator freezes when trying to open a file on Linux

Tags: linux, assembly, filesystems, mips, mars-simulator

I am running MARS 4.5 on Linux Mint with OpenJDK 8 and the program starts up fine and I can create a file. However, if I try to save or open another file, the program freezes and I have to kill the process.

The strange thing is that it worked one time, but after restarting the program, it was back to freezing whenever trying to access the filesystem.

I apologize if this is the wrong place for this kind of question, but I'm not sure where else to post it. If this is the wrong place, let me know and I will remove the question. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Any chance to try with Sun(Oracle) JRE/JDK? I have that one installed, and MARS works for me. But your description of problem sounds a bit more like some configuration/permission issue, another thing to check is maybe see the OpenJDK VM logs/stderr, if there's some hint about something happening. I don't know how to do that, I just managed to try `java -jar Mars4_5.jar` and then I did open + modify + save + compile short .asm file, and exit mars. I didn't get any additional output into console, just clean exit with no output. `java -version` -> `java version "1.8.0_151"`

Comment: @Ped7g Switching to the Sun JDK seems to have fixed it! Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Switching to the official jdk from Oracle seems to have fixed the problem. I followed [these instructions](https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1372) to uninstall OpenJDK and install the official one.